# Choose 38 different natural numbers less than 1000, Prove among these there exists at least two whose difference is at most 26.

Tags: combinatorics, pigeonhole-principle

Choose any 38 different natural numbers less than 1000.

Prove that among the selected numbers there exists at least two whose difference is at most 26.

I think I need to use pigeon hole principle, not sure where to even begin.

Comment: You can choose?

Comment: I feel like i'm misunderstanding what's going on. Can we not just suppose that all differences are larger then $x_1 -x_2 > 26$ but if $x_2 - x_1>26 $ then $0>52$

Comment: @Ben: The question would be clearer if "difference" is replaced by "distance".

Comment: @azimut I figured eventually thanks :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pigeonhole-principle is a good idea.

**Hint:** Think about partitioning $\{1,2,\ldots,999\}$ into subsets $\{1,2,\ldots,27\}$, $\{28,29,\ldots, 54\}$, $\{55,56,\ldots,81\}$, ..., $\{\ldots,998,999\}$ of size $27$ each.

Comment: Would that be 37 subsets then? By making them size 27 then if I choose 1 number from each subset, 37 total, then this would mean that by Pigeon hole principle two of my 38 numbers will be from 1 subset, and thus their difference would be at most 26. Is this right in any way?

Comment: Thanks for spotting this. I did a small mistake: The number 1000 is not in the range. I've modified my answer accordingly.

Comment: Just wondering is my answer okay though? Does it make sense?

Comment: @Dexter: Yes, it makes perfect sense. You got it!

Comment: @Dexter:  Yes, that is correct.  I am sure that was the intended answer as well.

Comment: Thanks, I think I just understood what pigeon hole principle is. Thank you!

Comment: @Dexter: You're welcome!

Answer (score 3):

Pigeonhole principle is not necessary.

Hint: Suppose the statement is false. Then $\exists x_1,x_2,\dots,x_38$ each less than $1000$. Suppose without loss of generality that $x_1<x_2<\dots<x_{38}$. Then it must be true that $x_2 \geq x_1 + 27$. Similarly $x_3 \geq x_2+27\geq x_1 + 27\times2$. What is the lower bound on $x_{38}$?

Comment: Beaten to it :-( +1 ;-)

Comment: @Ben Sorry about that, couldn't leave it unsaid!

Answer (score 3):

Reasoning by contradiction, so suppose that we can choose 38 natural numbers 
$$0< a_1<a_2<\cdots<a_{38}<1000$$
  such that the difference of any two numbers is at least 27. 
We can see easily that 
$$a_{n}\geq a_1+27(n-1),\forall n=1,\ldots,38, $$
so 
$$a_{38}\geq a_1+27\times37\geq1+27\times37=1000.$$
Contradiction. We conclude.